# Regex Match String Containing Word but not Word on its own

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a regex that will match any string including those containing `"hello"`, but not `"hello"` on it's own.

For example:

```
"hello1" - matches

"say hello" - matches

"hello there" - matches

"goodbye" - matches

"hello" - doesn't match
```

The following expression will match everything not containing `"hello"`, but I can't come up with an expression fitting the requirements.

```
^((?!hello).)*$
```

Unfortunately their cannot be extra logic associated with this. I am looking for a single expression that matches the above strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:((?!hello).)*|.+hello.*|.*hello.+)$
```

Took your original regex and added alternatives (`|`) to either:

- `.+hello.*` - have at least one character before the occurrence of `hello`
- `.*hello.+` - have at least one character after the occurrence of `hello`

---

Another solution is to just check the presence of the end of the string in the lookahead itself:

```
^(?!hello$).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, it may be more performant to check first, as a simple string match is fairly quick.  In PHP:

```
if($string != 'hello' && preg_match('/hello/', $string)) {
    // String contains hello, but is not only hello
}
```

Or you just don't even have to look, if the string is the length of the word you are looking for, as, if it matches, it will only be that word:

```
if(strlen($string) > 5 && preg_match('/hello/i', $string)) { }
```

Now, if you want to take into account spaces, or if it is just that word repeated, that is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I think just `(.+hello.*|.*hello.+)` from [ndn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755425/2423164) would be sufficient.

Comment: Click *edit* to check out the formatting for future reference.

Comment: However, note that this is not enough as it won't match in case the `hello` word in completely missing from the string.